# Anonymous Method in Object initializer

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-methods

I am creating a quiz in which have following class

`Quiz` with properties `CorrectOption`, `WrongOption1`, `WrongOption2`, `WrongOption3`.

in its `DTO` i have the `List<String> Options` that will contain all wrong and correct options.

While retrieving the entities i am using object initializer of DTO but don't know how to assign  `List<String> Options`.

I remember we use the anonymous methods to do so.

```
     select new QuestionDTO
                {
                    Category = q.QuizCategory.Text
                    ,
                    CorrectOption = q.CorrectOption
                    ,
                    DifficultyLevel = q.DifficultyLevel.Text
                    ,
                    Points = q.DifficultyLevel.Points.Value
                    ,
                    RewardPCT = q.DifficultyLevel.RewardPCT.Value
                    ,
                    Text = q.Text
                    ,
                    TimerDuration = q.DifficultyLevel.TimerDuration.Value
                    ,
                    Options = (qz) =>
                        {
                            List<string> ops = new List<string>();

                            ops.Add(q.CorrectOption);
                            ops.Add(q.WrongOption1);
                            ops.Add(q.WrongOption2);
                            ops.Add(q.WrongOption3);

                            return new List<string>().Shuffle();
                        }
                };
```

but it gives following error.

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' because it is not a delegate type.

**UPDATE**

For instance i have created a read only property on original entity class to do the work. but plz let me know the better way.
Thanks

**UPDATE2**

But it didn't work :p says following on WCFTestClient.exe

> The specified type member 'Options' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

Comment: Just a note: What are you doing with `ops`. Looks like you're populating it only to discard it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue. I was able to get around it by calling `ToList()` on the query and then a separate query for Select new {... }